# Javascript replace works in console, not in code

Tags: javascript, replace

I've been trying to setup a small booking system however I'm stuck.  Basically, I add all the seat numbers that want to be booked into a string eg (a22~b20~f10).  However when a seat is deselected it needs to be removed from the string.  I have tried using .replace but to no avail, even in the console.

I then tried the code below.  It works brilliantly in the console, but not at all in my code.

```
seatNumbersToBook.split(seatNumber+"~").join("");
```

The full function is here

```
var seatNumbersToBook = "";

function calcSeats(calc, seatNumber){

    if(amountSeatsToBeBooked != 0 && seatNumber != "NaN" && calc == "-1"){
        seatNumbersToBook = seatNumber + "~" + seatNumbersToBook;
    }        

    if(calc == "+1"){
        //remove from seatNumbersToBook array
        seatNumbersToBook.split(seatNumber+"~").join("");

        console.log(seatNumber);
    }

    // despite removing seat number from array, still MUST check in array to see if the seatnumber has already been recorded

    amountSeatsToBeBooked = eval(amountSeatsToBeBooked + calc);

    $("#remainingSeatsToBeBooked").html(amountSeatsToBeBooked);

    console.log(seatNumbersToBook);

    return amountSeatsToBeBooked;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You don't even have `.replace()` in your code.

Comment: Why don't you use an Actual array

Comment: @zerkms no, I took it out because it didn't work so there was no point in keeping it.

Comment: @OJay Because of the way other things work an array starts to get annoying.  And this was supposed to be simple

Comment: @Jacbey can't comment on `how other things work` but reinventing some sort of pseudo string markup and keeping a count of how many seats are left by `eval`ing a string, doesn't seem simple to me in the slightest. Two arrays of 'availableSeats' and 'bookedSeats' that are mutually exclusive would be simpler to understand and use standard data structures. Or perhaps an array of `seat` objects that have an attribute of booked true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the split() then join() but don't assign the result back to seatNumbersToBook, so seatNumbersToBook is still old value

Comment: How come it works absolutely fine exactly as it is in the console?  It just doesn't make sense.  Also, is this what you mean?

    seatNumbersToBook = seatNumbersToBook.split(seatNumber+"~").join("");

Comment: in the console, when you enter that expression, it will evaluate and print out the result, so it does make sense for me. There is no problem with the expression, the result is correct, but you dont store the result only.

Comment: "to no avail" --- what does it mean?

Comment: @PhuongNguyen I got it to work, thanks so much for your help and please excuse my simple mindedness at this hour.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
String.prototype.split() and Array.prototype.join() does not change the string or array itself but returns a new string or array